# Clean-up method doesn't get called from window unload in IE9

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer

When a user closes a browser tab or window the following javascript is called

```
   Event.observe(window, 'unload', function(){
         alert(WINDOW CLOSING!);
         methodCleanUp();
    }
```

methodCleanUp() invokes an action, via an async request, implemented in java code, not on the web page.
The alert is called in all browsers, BUT IE9 doesn't fire the method whereas Mozilla & Chrome are fine - almost as if IE is too eager to close.
This didn't happen in the RTM IE9 release, only after installing the security updates

Any ideas or advice

Comment: You know that the provided snippet is **not** syntaxically valid, right? If yes, could you correct it?

Comment: @sp00m Yeah obviously this is just an example, the code is not the problem, as said all other browsers invoke the method correctly just IE since the updates doesn't

Comment: If I move the alert to after the call to the cleanup method and watch the logs everything works as long as I wait!

Comment: So just have to insert a timeout to delay IE